# Android app having problems displaying a ProgressBar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

Here is the section for the progressbar in the activity :

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBarLogin"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText_password"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Here is the code for the OnCreate:

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBarLogin);
    myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
    // progress bar is hidden (yay!)
    // other stuff goes here
 }
```

Here is the code for the button callback:

```
    final Button loginButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // login button was clicked
            try {
                // myCommandSender is a thread:
                myCommandSender.start()        
                waitForCommandSender();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code in this thread that waits for myCommandSender to finish:

```
    private void waitForCommandSender() {
    myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    while (myCommandSender.isAlive()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to change the Visibility from different Thread than UI main thread. Only original thread that created View hierarchy can touch it - that might be the problem. But to know more - what error messages are shown?

Comment: No errors, it just doesn't pop up. I did have the exception you are talking about, but I put the progress bar control and construction into the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that, At first, you need to **call the waitForCommandSender(); method** after that you need to start the thread

```
 final Button loginButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
  loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // login button was clicked
        try {
            // myCommandSender is a thread:
            //call the method first and start thread next
             waitForCommandSender();
            myCommandSender.start()      

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is that going to work?  waitForCommandSender is in a loop waiting for comandSender to finish (its calling "while (myCommandSender.isAlive())")

Answer (score 0):

setContentView(R.layout.______) is missing in onCreate() of activity. Hence you'll never be able to the UI. Please add it in activity and check it